# font-awesome link makes icon blue. how do you change this color?

Tags: hyperlink, font-awesome

```
 <a href="#resume" rel="facebox">
    <i class="fa fa-align-left"></i>
 </a>
```

I couldn't find where it changes icon to blue..

How do you change its color?

Comment: mate, what css framework are you using in your project? We need more info to answer your question

Answer (score 6):

icons inherit the `color` property from his parents. Maybe you can specify like this

```
a .fa {
color: #777;
}
```